# Xamarin.Forms - Turning off ActivityIndicator using Activity States

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms

In `Xamarin.Forms`, I have an `ActivityIndicator` and a `label` that pops up when a video is loading and I wish to correctly disable it when the video is fully loaded.

I have a binding in my code "this.IsBusy" that correctly enables/disables the `ActivityIndicator`.

I notice in my debug, I receive this message when the video starts:

```
05-05 14:17:09.843 V/MediaPlayer-JNI(19723): isPlaying: 1
```

**QUESTION:** How can I use this `isPlaying` state to turn my "this.IsBusy" to become false? Is it possible? Or do I need a custom renderer to make this all happen.

Below is my XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PreAppStructure"
         xmlns:roxv="clr-namespace:Rox;assembly=Rox.Xamarin.Video.Portable"
         x:Class="PreAppStructure.Page3"
         Title="Welcome to page 3">
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <roxv:VideoView x:Name="VideoView" AutoPlay="True" LoopPlay="True" ShowController="True" Source="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" />
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" IsVisible="True">
            <ActivityIndicator Color="White"
                x:Name="loader"
                IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" 
                VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            <Label x:Name ="loadingtext" Text="Loading...Please wait!" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="White" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>                
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Below is my C# class:

```
...
using Rox;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace PreAppStructure
{
    public partial class Page3 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = this;
            this.IsBusy = true; // Activity Indicator is now successfully visible!   
            // When the app reaches the "isPlaying" state, I wish the Activity Indicator to not be visible (false)
        }   //On this line, the page loads, video buffers and then the video plays        
    }
}
```